# OpenSSL errors - ClamAV build on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, openssl, antivirus

I am trying to build ClamAV from source which I downloaded from here: http://www.clamav.net/downloads. I downloaded clamav-0.99.tar.gz.

I open `ClamAV.sln` under the win32 folder of the download inside Visual Studio 2010. However, when I build it I get these errors:

[image]

Error:
`error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/ssl.h' No such file or directory`

I also get a variety of undefined errors. I didn't change any code so I don't understand why I'm getting these errors. I installed OpenSSL and added to my PATH but I'm still getting it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You need to provide a sample of the errors output from the build log. You should do it because: (1) the text is too small to read for some folks; and (2) search engines cannot index the text from an image.

Comment: I added the error as text. Forgot about search engines, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the path to OpenSSL headers to the projects that need them. To do so, open the project's Properties window and go to `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`.

You will probably need to specify the path to its link libraries also. Specify folders at `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` and specify actual file names at  `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`.

Comment: Thank you, the openssl errors went away. I don't have a `Linker` option in `Configuration Properties`. Why do you think that is? I searched Google but couldn't find out anything.

Comment: The `Linker` option will show up only for projects that produce executables since they may need to be linked against libraries. Projects that produce libraries will not have that option because there is no linking step.