# LNK1181 errors when building ClamAV

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, build, linker

I am trying to build ClamAV and am running into Linker errors. I tried doing what was said here in the answer: [OpenSSL errors - ClamAV build on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539175/clamav-build-on-windows-10) for the Linker part, however, I don't see any Linker option in Visual Studio 2010.

This is what the project properties look like: [image]

There is nothing in `Common Properties` either. These are the errors I'm getting:

[image]

> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libeay32.lib'
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libeay32.lib'
> - warning C4090: '=' : different 'const' qualifiers
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\clamav-0.99\win32\Win32\Release\libclamav.lib'
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libeay32.lib'
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\clamav-0.99\win32\Win32\Release\libclamav.lib'
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\clamav-0.99\win32\Win32\Release\libclamav.lib'
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\clamav-0.99\win32\Win32\Release\libclamav.lib'
> - error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Mo\Desktop\clamav-0.99\win32\Win32\Release\libclamav.lib'
> - Unable to find source file 'C:\clamdeps\win32\openssl\lib\ssleay32.dll' for file 'ssleay32.dll', located in '[TARGETDIR]', the file may be absent or locked.
> - Unable to find source file 'C:\clamdeps\win32\openssl\lib\libeay32.dll' for file 'libeay32.dll', located in '[TARGETDIR]', the file may be absent or locked.

Would anyone have any idea on how I can fix this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I installed it and included the `openssl` directory under `Configuration Properties > General> Additional include Directories`.

Comment: Is there more than 1 target in the solution? You seem to have seleted the target of a static library and not an executable. You will not have a Linker setting on a static Library.

Comment: This is what's in the solution: http://i.imgur.com/OZmhBb5.png I'm not sure which one to pick, so I included the `openssl` directory in all of them (except the Setups).

Comment: clamscan is probably what you want. Check the Output window for what targets failed to compile.

Comment: When you say target, are you talking about the projects as seen in the second picture in the OP in the last column?

Comment: Yes the projects. Sorry, CMake calls them targets and I use CMake for all of my stuff now..

Comment: Alright, I see the `Linker` option in those projects. Going to try to include the `openssl` libraries and build again. I'll let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got rid of all those errors and warnings. However, I have another problem. Not sure if I should make a new thread but here it is: http://i.imgur.com/d95AfDB.png (This happens after building). Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: That means you have the wrong startup project in Visual Studio. Choose an executable project not a static library.